# Special character bindings stopped working after some update

Tags: neovim

I was trying to add a pluggin to my nvim when I strarted fixing my :checkhealth

I ran few commands:

```
pip3 install pynvim
yarn global add neovim
npm install -g neovim
gem install neovim
gem environment
```

Then, I noticed few binding were not working anymore:

```
nnoremap _ V
nnoremap \| <C-r>
```

(and probably few others)

In the my (dvorak) keyboard, those bindings are shifted binding of special keys and for some reasons when I press them, I get a result like if I was pressing `<HOME>`.

I tried to check the `:map _` and `:verbose map _` and it is binded correctly.

Furthermore, I had another nvim openned before I made the modifications and the bindings were still working.

I cannot figue out why its not working. Any idea? thanks

EDIT: even with the command `nvim --noplugin -u /dev/null` and then manually setting up the binding, it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed to be a bugged.
Workaround: `nnoremap <S-_> V`